# Equals() between objects of inconvertible types SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

in all my insertData methods im getting this warning

```
fun insertDataOwnerTable(nickname: String, ownername: String, ownersPhone: String,
                         pin: Int, dateSignup: String, country: String,
                         ownersMail: String): Boolean {

    val db = this.writableDatabase
    val cv = ContentValues()
    cv.put(NICKNAME_COL, nickname)
    cv.put(NAME_COL, ownername)
    cv.put(PHONE_COL, ownersPhone)
    cv.put(USER_PIN, pin)
    cv.put(DATE_SIGNUP, dateSignup)
    cv.put(OWNERS_COUNTRY, country)
    cv.put(OWNERS_EMAIL, ownersMail)
    val insertDataOwners = db.insert(TABLE1_NAME, null, cv)

    return !insertDataOwners.equals(-1) //equals() between objects of inconvertible types
}
```

I tried to correct it

```
return !insertDataOwners.equals(other = -1) // does not solves the warning
```

What is the correct solution to eliminate that warning?

Answer (score 2):

[`insert()` returns a `Long`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase?hl=en#insert). `-1` is an `Int`.

So, rewrite:

```kotlin
return !insertDataOwners.equals(-1)
```

to be:

```kotlin
return insertDataOwners != -1L
```

This compares a `Long` with a `Long`, and it uses more natural syntax for the not-equals comparison operation.